# Python: what's the pythonic way to perform this loop?

Tags: python

What is the pythonic way to perform this loop. I'm trying to pick a random key that will return a subtree and not the root. Hence: 'parent == None' cannot be true. Nor can 'isRoot==True' be true.

```
thekey = random.choice(tree.thedict.keys())
while (tree.thedict[thekey].parent == None)or(tree.thedict[thekey].isRoot == True):
        thekey = random.choice(tree.thedict.keys())
.......
```

edit: it works now

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Knowing the type of the values in `thedict` would be very useful.

Comment: get a random subtree that is not the root. so if the parent is none, or the flag 'isRoot' is True, I want it to get another random key, and then check it

Comment: We may need to see the rest of that while loop.  What you have so far seems fine, although it seems like `parent == None` and `isRoot == True` ought to be logically equivalent.

Comment: Thats the whole of the while loop. You're right, the two conditions should only occur together. I'm checking to see that they do. (in another part of the code)

Comment: wouldn't an `assert` statement be better for ensuring those conditions always occur together?

Comment: @Jweede: no, `assert`s are for documenting conditions that can't possibly occur during program execution.

Comment: I edited the question. I had mistakenly pit "tree.thedict[thekey].parent.isRoot == True". parent should not be there.

Comment: I tried the code after the edit and it works. I'm still interested in all these comments on a pythonic way to do this

Comment: if the two conditions should only occur together, and this is checked somewhere else, the conditions occurring separately is a potential bug and should be asserted

Comment: Now that you have edited the code and it works, please edit the question.  I spent some time scratching my head, trying to figure out why the code didn't work; it looked to me like it should work.  Finally I expanded the hidden comments and found out that the code I'm looking at now *does* work!  I don't have enough points to just go in and edit it for you, so I can't just do it myself.

Comment: @ Dustin Thanks, I'll do that.

Comment: @Peter Stewart: the "Edit it works now" is a terrible, terrible thing.  Please fix your question to BE your ACTUAL question.  Clean, simple, precise.  Then Accept one answer the answers your question.

Comment: @ S.Lott: Thank you. I fixed it up. I really made a mess of this question. As a beginner, I came here to learn what other peoples choice of a best answer would be. Bonvallet will be my choice now. I'm still open to opinions.

Comment: Isn't it bad to compare agaisnt True or False?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
key = random.choice([key for key, subtree in tree.thedict.items()
                         if subtree.parent and not subtree.isRoot])
```

(Corrected after comments and question edition)

Comment: That doesn't exactly do the same thing. This may be omitting loop body code from a larger loop that does stuff to thedict.

Comment: There is no larger loop. This looks very succinct.

Comment: This is a very expensive way to solve the problem.  You are building a list of every key and subtree in the tree, which will be slow and will take a lot of memory if the tree is large.  Then this list is used just once and discarded.  If you know the tree will always be small, then this succinct code might be a good choice.  But if you were putting this in a library, I wouldn't do it this way.  Other solutions, which use a loop to retry if the random choice is the root, will almost always execute the loop exactly once, and don't need any extra storage.

Comment: If this is a one-time operation, I think the succintness is worth the little penalty. If the choice needs to be made several times and it has been found to be the bottleneck, one choice would be to create the candidate list once and then reuse it.

Comment: ...besides, the question was about pythonicity, not efficiency :P

Comment: Well, I have a personal preference for code that is both simple and flexible.  Even if you know today that the code will only be run once, do you know the program will never be changed to need that code to run multiple times?  If you cache the list, you need to be sure the tree didn't change after you cached it.  In this case, there is a simple solution that is also fast (see my answer), so I vote for it.  Socking, I know, that I would prefer my own answer, but there you go.  :-)  You don't have to agree, of course.

Comment: Er, "shocking" is spelled "shocking" and not "socking".  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

> get a random subtree that is not the
>   root

```
not_root_nodes = [key, node for key,node in tree.thedict.iteritems() if not ( node.parent is None or node.isRoot)]
item = random.choice( not_root_nodes )
```

Comment: This won't work, since `random.choice` doesn't take generators as arguments.  The argument should be a list.

Comment: This builds a list of all the nodes in the tree, each time you run it; then it picks one node and discards the list.  For large trees, this will be very expensive.  I hope we can find a solution that is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
thekey = random.choice(tree.thedict.keys())
parent = thedict[thekey].parent
while parent is None or parent.isRoot:
    thekey = random.choice(tree.thedict.keys())
    parent = thedict[thekey].parent
```

Comment: You negated the first conditional test.

Comment: Also, `thekey.parent` makes no sense.

Comment: thekey is just a key and not a node in the tree. Also I think he wants to know if thedict[thekey] is the root, not if the parent is the root.

Comment: @ ntownsend, you're right. I want to know if the key is the root , not if the parent is the root.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a bit better:

```
theDict = tree.thedict

def getKey():
    return random.choice(theDict.keys())

theKey = getKey()

while theDict[thekey].parent in (None, True):
    thekey = getKey()
```

What do you think?

Comment: What does it mean for theDict[thekey].parent to be True? You need to check if theDict[thekey].isRoot is True.

Comment: I think he was checking for isRoot==True, not parent==True.  :-)

Comment: I wanted to do it without using a function

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_root(v): 
  assert (v.parent != None) == (v.isRoot)
  return v.isRoot
  #note how dumb this function looks when you guarantee that assertion

def get_random_nonroot_key():
  while True:
    thekey = random.choice(tree.thedict.keys())
    value = tree.thedict[thekey]
    if not is_root(value): return key
```

or a refactoring of Roberto Bonvallet's answer

```
def get_random_nonroot_key():
  eligible_keys = [k for k, v in tree.thedict.items() if not is_root(v)]
  return random.choice(eligible_keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your while condition is flawed:

I think you expect this: **`tree.thedict[thekey].parent == None`**
should be equal to this: **`tree.thedict[thekey].parent.isRoot == True`**

When in fact, for both to mean "this node is not the root", you should change the second statement to: **`tree.thedict[thekey].isRoot == True`**

As written, your conditional test says "while this node is the root OR this node's parent is the root". If your tree structure is a single root node with many leaf nodes, you should expect an infinite loop in this case.

Here's a rewrite:

```
thekey = random.choice(k for k in tree.thedict.keys() if not k.isRoot)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
thekey = random.choice(tree.thedict.keys())
parent = tree.thedict[thekey].parent
while parent is None or tree.thedict[thekey].isRoot:
    thekey = random.choice(tree.thedict.keys())
    parent = thedict[thekey].parent
```

Comment: That looks a little more readable. I see you caught my error referencing '.parent' in the second condition.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't like the repetition of initializing thekey before the while loop and then again inside the loop.  It's a possible source of bugs; what happens if someone edits one of the two initializations and forgets to edit the other?  Even if that never happens, anyone reading the code needs to check carefully to make sure both initializations match perfectly.

I would write it like so:

```
while True:
    thekey = random.choice(tree.thedict.keys())
    subtree = tree.thedict[thekey]
    if subtree.parent is not None and not subtree.isRoot:
        break
```

P.S. If you really just want the subtree, and don't care about the key needed to lookup the subtree, you could even do this:

```
while True:
    subtree = random.choice(tree.thedict.values())
    if subtree.parent is not None and not subtree.isRoot:
        break
```

Some people may not like the use of "`while True:`" but that is the standard Python idiom for "loop forever until something runs `break`".  IMHO this is simple, clear, idiomatic Python.

P.P.S. This code should really be wrapped in an if statement that checks that the tree has more than one node.  If the tree only has a root node, this code would loop forever.

Comment: I didn't know about 'while true:   break ' and would not have seen it as pythonic. I will be a handy thing to know.